# Optimize rendering thousands of elements

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, dispatcher

I'm facing a big problem with optimizing rendering a lot of custom controls. I'm developing a system that will be diplaying thousand custom controls and update several values of these controls every second or frequently. There will be also support for zooming and panning. But I found out that rendering(on canvas) takes a lot of time, zooming and panning is laggy.
Does anyone have an experience with this kind of wpf application?

Comment: I have found that overloading your users with information is a bad thing. Do you really have to show them thousands of things on screen at once?

Comment: @Simon My client has these requirements. During testing I found out that's almost impossible to monitor all controls. In my oponion optimal number of controls is around 300-500. But the problem with rendering and zooming is still here.

Comment: You need have keyboard and mouse support for these all elements? If not you can use visual layer and draw "elements" with DrawingVisual class or another lower level object.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is almost always due to inadvertently disabling virtualization and container recycling, usually through styling/templating. My first step would be to examine the WPF Tree Visualizer at run-time and make sure you're only drawing the elements that are actually visible on-screen.

Comment: just that he is using a canvas and not any type of panel that can be placed in an items control.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by this comment. An `ItemsControl` panel can be replaced with a `Canvas` and as [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx) shows it can be virtualized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BitmapCache` to disable rerendering controls that have not changed.

In my experience this greatly improves zooming and panning performance.

Enable it for the more complex controls.

Example:

```
<Rectangle CacheMode="BitmapCache" />

<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache/>
    </Rectangle.CacheMode>
</Rectangle>
```

Details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-4.aspx)

Comment: I think you are right. Caching can be the best way how to deal with this problem. Especially with idea mentioned by @markE. Do you think it is better to cache Canvas which contains controls or apply caching on the individual parts of controls?

Comment: I recommend to cache individual complex controls, but it is trial and error in my experience

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 canvases that are the same size and at the same position (a top canvas overlaying a bottom canvas).

Bottom Canvas: displays all controls.  This is a static image (cached) which might get refreshed every 30 seconds or so.

Top Canvas: displays every control that has changed in the last 30 seconds.

The 2 canvases are exactly aligned so every recently-changed control on the top canvas will exactly obscure its out-of-date twin on the bottom canvas.

This way you only have to draw the few controls that have changed rather than all thousand controls.